# How to dynamically take a imageview from an ImageView List and place that imageview to an imageview variable

Tags: java, android

If I have an array/list full of imageviews- `List<ImageView> iv;` where I dynamically add a few pics/icons/images, and I have a variable from type imageview called IV and a number between the lengths of

0 to the length of the list-1,

how can I take the imageview from the list/array and set it to IV which is our variable which is imageview type?

this is what I tried:
`IV=(iv.get(num));`
but nothing seems to happen as in the image in our variable imageview doesn't change

doing this all dynamically using java, no xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. Make sure to check for null.

```
IV.setImageDrawable(iv.get(num).getDrawable());
```

Comment: you forgot brackets at the end- getDrawable() lol. thanks:P